# How should I create an index based on the dynamic SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, multi-index

I want to optimize the performance of the following SQL query by creating an index. The query filters results based on input variables, allowing null values for optional filtering. I'm specifically interested in PostgreSQL solutions. How can I create an index to speed up this query?

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
WHERE (:code IS NULL OR p.code = :code)
  AND (:barcode IS NULL OR p.barcode = :barcode)
  AND (:category_id IS NULL OR p.category_id = :category_id)
  AND (:brand_id IS NULL OR p.brand_id = :brand_id)
ORDER BY p.last_modified_date;
```

When null values are passed to the variables, the corresponding condition is disabled. The variables are obtained from a filterable page.

Comment: How many of the variables are you expecting to be null? Is this only ever going to have one non-null value or could there be two to four non-null values given.

Comment: How many indexes can you afford? Are there any foreign keys, primary key or unique constraints already?

Comment: Data distribution, cardinality etc make a difference too. E.g. category_id is probably less interesting as an index first column - if there are few different categories.

Comment: Don't do that. Write a different query depending on the parameters you get.

Comment: @MartinBrown some of them or all of them can be null.

Comment: @jarlh  There is a unique index on the 'barcode' and 'code' columns. There is a primary key, and additionally, there are four foreign keys.

Comment: This is a "kitchen sink" query. I suggest you google why this is bad

Answer (score 0):

No.

Build the query on the fly.  If `:code` is null, leave out that part of the `WHERE` clause.  Etc.

Then you will have a mishmash of combinations.  Build a few likely 2-column indexes.  Let them server for cases where you need an index on the first of the two columns.  That is, `INDEX(code, barcode)` will work for either of these:

```
 WHERE p.code = :code
   AND p.barcode = :barcode
```

and

```
 WHERE p.code = :code
   -- without testing for barcode.
```